# Stream synthetized audio in real time in flutter

Tags: flutter, audio

I'm trying to create an app generating a continuos sinewave of various frequency (controlled by the user) and I'm trying to play the data as it's generated in real time.

I'm using [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) right now to play bytes generated using [wave_generator](https://pub.dev/packages/wave_generator), as follows (snippet from [issue](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/187)):

```
class BufferAudioSource extends StreamAudioSource {
  final Uint8List _buffer;

  BufferAudioSource(this._buffer) : super(tag: "Bla");

  @override
  Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) {
    start = start ?? 0;
    end = end ?? _buffer.length;



    return Future.value(
      StreamAudioResponse(
        sourceLength: _buffer.length,
        contentLength: end - start,
        offset: start,
        contentType: 'audio/wav',

        stream: Stream.value(List<int>.from(_buffer.skip(start).take(end - start))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I'm using the audio source like this:

```
StreamAudioSource _source = BufferAudioSource(_data!);
_player.setAudioSource(_source);
_player.play()
```

Is there a way I could feed the data to the player as soon as I generate it on the fly, using a sinewave generator, so that if the user changes the frequency, the playback will reflect the change as soon as it happens?

I tried looking online and on the repository github but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: You’re looking to do real time DSP. Flutter is mainly aimed at UI and the right platform for that kind of application. Your only option, if you want to stick with flutter, is to delve into the native APIs and create a wrapper for them.

Comment: Look at what the community has been asking https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bflutter%5D%5Baudio%5D+real+time and the sound stream library https://pub.dev/packages/sound_stream